# onclick action not working with a scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, onclick

I am experiencing the weirdest of bugs...

here is the excerpt of the part that is not working:

```
$(function(){
        $("#button1").click(function(event) {
            $("#button2").hide();
            return false;
            event.preventDefault();
})
});
</script>

            <div data-role="footer" id="m-footer">
                <div class="first-row ui-grid-b">
                    <div class="ui-block-a left">
                        <a  id="button1" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-icon-custom ui-btn-icon-top" data-icon="custom" data-transition="none"><img src="media/icon_1.png"/ ></a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="button2" class="ui-block-b center">
                        <a  onclick="alert('click');" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-icon-custom ui-btn-icon-top" data-icon="custom" data-transition="none"><img src="media/icon_2.png"/ ></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-c right">
                        <a  onclick="alert('click');" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-icon-custom ui-btn-icon-top" data-icon="custom" data-transition="none"><img src="media/icon_3.png"/ ></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have a popup box containing six buttons, each linked to a "onclick" action. When the window is big enough and the popup isn't scrollable, the actions are working just fine. But if i resize the window, and the div becomes scrollable, suddendly the buttons don't work anymore: clicking on them will result in the popup scrolling up to the top and the action being totally ignored.

I've already implemented *return false*.

**This only happens on Chrome and Safari - not on Firefox.**

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have to provide the *actual* HTML/JS, but a working demonstration with dummy code would help you get an answer.

Comment: Have you try with `$( "#mydiv" ).on("click", function(){})`. What I'm thinking it's maybe your onclick function is not trigger anymore because for a mysterious reason the link is break. Maybe if you didn't try yet "on" function, it could work. Normally "on" function is trigger on element created after the DOM is ready.

Comment: Inspect using chrome devtools and see if the control is going to the button onclick action on click. If not, than your button might not even be getting clicked. Check the z-index of buttons and content above and below. Sometimes margin & padding overlaps with your content in case you are using position:fixed or absolute.

Comment: i've added the code excerpt, if it can help!

@JiteshYadav how do i check if the button is being clicked? the div scrolls to the top, so something is happening, but it's not the action i wanted (a console log, an alert message or whatever)

Comment: @dogen Open your webpage in chrome and press F12, it will open dev tools. Click on source and open your js file where the onclick action is written. Put a breakpoint and see if control reaches there. If yes then button is getting clicked else not. Refer https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging for more details on how to debug js in chrome dev tools.

Comment: @JiteshYadav you were right, javascript isn't even being triggered. but the <a> is being clicked: the button's color get darker for a moment (its active state) and the div scrolls to the top.

Comment: @dogen it's not possible that just by changing the width control stops going to anchor tag onclick action. If it's working in big window then it must work in small window as well unless you are not able to click on that anchor itself. As suggested before try using inspect in chrome and see if the actual anchor is overlapped by some other div or something. Most likely you actual anchor you want to click is overlapped by some other anchor/div.

Comment: No other div overlapped the buttons. Adding an empty link to the ancor solved the problem: <a **href=""** id="button1" class=  .... 

Thank you @JiteshYadav for your help

Comment: @dogen good to know you solved it :)